# Convert Java EE 7 EL Map to a dynamic value from a forEach loop

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, dictionary, foreach, el

I currently have a task to dynamically generate content that is now static. The problem is that the sessionScope variable from EL is used to toggle the rendering of content. Since sessionScope is a Map, I don't really know how to convert it to be used in a forEach loop.

Current layout:

```
<p:outputPanel layout="block">
    <p:commandLink id="testId">
        <p:graphicImage value="#{request.contextPath}/images/test.jpg" />
        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{!sessionScope.renderContentA}" target="#{sessionScope.renderContentA}" />
    </p:commandLink>
    <pe:tooltip for="testId" value="TestTooltip" />
</p:outputPanel>

<p:outputPanel layout="block">
    <p:commandLink id="testId2">
        <p:graphicImage value="#{request.contextPath}/images/test2.jpg" />
        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{!sessionScope.renderContentB}" target="#{sessionScope.renderContentB}" />
    </p:commandLink>
    <pe:tooltip for="testId2" value="TestTooltip" />
</p:outputPanel>
```

Which I need to convert to:

```
<c:forEach items="#{bean.items}" var="item">
    <p:outputPanel layout="block">
            <p:commandLink id="#{item.id}">
                <p:graphicImage value="#{request.contextPath.concat(item.imageUrl)}" />
                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{!SOMETHING-HERE}" target="#{SOMETHING-HERE}" />
            </p:commandLink>
            <pe:tooltip for="#{item.id}" value="TestTooltip" />
    </p:outputPanel>
</c:forEach>
```

An example where it's used (which I need to adjust aswell):

```
<p:outputPanel autoUpdate="true" style="float: right;">
    <p:commandLink rendered="#{!sessionScope.renderContentA}">
        <h:outputText styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-plus"  />
        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{!sessionScope.renderContentA}" target="#{sessionScope.renderContentA}" />
    </p:commandLink>
    <p:commandLink rendered="#{sessionScope.renderContentA}">
        <h:outputText styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-minus"  />
        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{!sessionScope.renderContentA}" target="#{sessionScope.renderContentA}" />
    </p:commandLink>
</p:outputPanel>
```

I've been Googling for a while now, but can't find a good answer. I'm using Glassfish 4, Java EE 7, EL 3 and JSF 2.1.1-b04. If I need to provide something else, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the sollution after some trial and error with a collegue. You can access sessionScope with a plain array-like approach.

```
<f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{!sessionScope[item.uniqueName]}" target="#{sessionScope[item.uniqueName]}" />
```